# switching screens and transition screens for an app in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

This is a two part question.
The first question:

So I have an app that transitions from one screen to another, using nib files. heres the code i use to switch screens:

```
self.transitionView = [[TransitionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TransitionViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview: self.transitionView.view];
```

my problem is i have about 30 - 40 lines of code in the viewdidload method that could conceivably be slowing the transition down slightly, as some of the code uses NSURL to read data in, but its a 2 - 3 second wait between when it enters the viewdidload method and when the view actually finishes loading. the line `[super viewdidload]` is at the very top of all of this too, which is the most confusing part. so why is my program taking 2 - 3 seconds to load? i think thats a pretty long time considering how little code i have there.

part 2 of the question is i want to create a transition screen that appears for 2 - 3 seconds before the actual screen loads. Ive taken that code out and for some reason my nib file still takes forever to load so i know it has nothing to do with that, but the transition screen needs to pop up BEFORE screen 2 for 3 seconds, even if the app is being opened after 10 minutes. i know there was a function in appdelegate that could assist in this endeavor but im at a loss for what the code should look like. it doesnt seem to be switching with

```
self.transitionView = [[TransitionViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TransitionViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.view addSubview: self.transitionView.view];
```

and aside from that, im at a loss for an understanding about how the code should be constructed to switch between screens in that fashion. any articles or suggestions anybody can give me?

**EDIT**

I also tried to separate the NSURL data in the viewdidload method from the method itself. i put it all in a method called initialize, and called it from screen 1 right after calling the 2nd view. it didnt help the switching time at all. the reason i did that is because i didnt want to receive all the nsurl data over again when the person opens the app. i just want them to retrieve it one time and be done with it. am i doing somethign wrong here? this is extremely frustrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put your transition effects in viewdidload , you should put them in viewdidappear or viewwillappear, that is the the next step that the controller will take after it is loaded. That is your best choice, as for the screen to to put it there, you need to load it using the nib file or in the viewdidload.
I hope that was helpful

Comment: what is viewdidload doing?

Comment: viewdidload loads the view from the superview, it loads the basic UI and APIs of the controller, it needs time to load.